# If my constructor takes in two files, how do I call StdIn.readLine() on only one of the files?

Tags: java

My constructor takes in two arguments--each is a String that refers to a file. I want to use StdIn.readLine() on only one of them so that I can save the information into a set. How do I do this?

Comment: [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: Why use StdIn, if you want to read from a specific file, rather than from standard input?

Comment: 1. Write code that does it for both of them. 2. Delete half the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by StdIn.readLine() and I suspect you may be thinking of another programming language. In Java 8, I would do something like this:

```
Set<String> strSet = new HashSet<>();
Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt");
try {
    Files.lines(path).forEach(line -> strSet.add(line));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And basically, you do it for only one filepath, and not the other.

Comment: I did a search for the combination of java and StdIn. It appears to be a class that provides static methods used in some Princeton courses for formatted reading from `System.in`. See the [documentation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html). I don't see its relevance to reading from a named file.